# How do I include data from the order item type fields in the order receipt email?

Tags: 8, commerce, emails

I have created an "Event Registration" product type and order item type. In the order item type, I added fields for the registrant's name and job title. How can I print the submitted values for those fields in the commerce-order-receipt.html.twig?

Comment: I tried {{ order_item.field_job_itle }}, but that results in an error ("Exception: Object of type Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList cannot be printed. in Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter() (line 476 of /home/mysite/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigExtension.php).")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! Took a few steps:

1. I created a View of type: Order Item. Added my custom fields to that view (Job Title, etc).
2. Added a Contextual Filter "Order item: ID".
   Provide Default Value: Content ID from URL.
3. I created a Viewfield on
   each of my Order Item Types, using the View I created in the
   previous step.
4. I went to
   /admin/commerce/config/order-item-types/default/edit/display and hid
   all the fields except for the Viewfield. Repeat for the other Order
   Item Types. In commerce-order-receipt.html.twig, add this code
   (which was found in commerce-checkout-order-summary.html.twig):

   ```
   {{ order_item|commerce_entity_render('summary') }}
   ```
5. Style the output as you like in the receipt twig. Here is the
   pertinent portion of mine in case anyone finds it helpful:

   ```
           <tr>
             <td>
               {% block order_items %}
               <table style="padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom:15px; width: 100%">
                 <tbody style="text-align: left;">
                 {% for order_item in order_entity.getItems %}
                 <tr>
                   <td>
                     <span style="font-size: 15px;">
               {{ order_item.getQuantity|number_format }} x 
               <span style="font-weight: bold;">{{ order_item.label }}</span>
               <span style="float: right;">{{ order_item.getTotalPrice|commerce_price_format }}</span>
             </span>
             <br>
             {{ order_item|commerce_entity_render('summary') }}
             <br><br><hr><br>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
                 {% endfor %}
                 </tbody>
               </table>
               {% endblock %}
             </td>
           </tr>
   ```
6. Clear cache, and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

I just needed one product attribute (with field machine name 'field_message') to be included in the item rows in the e-mail, so I adapted the template like this:

```
      {% for order_item in order_entity.getItems %}
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{ order_item.getQuantity|number_format }} x
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ order_item.label }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {% if order_item.field_message.value %}
            {{ order_item.field_message.value }}
          {% endif %}
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">
          {{ order_item.getTotalPrice|commerce_price_format }}</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
```

So if the order_item has a value for field_message, that value goes into a new third table column (if not then the cell is empty), with the fourth column now right-aligned with the total price as before.

And instead of putting this commerce-order-receipt.html.twig file in a new custom module, I just included it in my existing custom theme (in its templates directory), with the following in the THEMENAME.theme file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function THEMENAME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'commerce_order_receipt' => [
      'template' => 'commerce-order-receipt',
      'base hook' => 'commerce_order_receipt',
    ],
  ];
}
```